# «Кадавер» или «кадавр»?

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия

И если правильно «кадавер» — произносится «е» или «э»? Т. е. предыдущий согласный смягчается или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Толковый словарь медицинского сленга:](http://med_slang.academic.ru/68/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)

> Кадавер - умирающий больной

**[Сadaver](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/cadaver)** - труп, предназначенный для вскрытия, научного изучения или демонстрации.

> Происходит от лат. cadaver «труп, мёртвое тело», далее из cadere
>   «падать», из праиндоевр. *kad- «падать». Англ. cadaver — примерно с
>   1500 г. (Использованы материалы Online Etymology Dictionary Дугласа
>   Харпера.)

См. [КАДАВР](http://gallicismes.academic.ru/16888/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> *перен.* Cadavre-то я cadavre, но не могу сказать, что на все соглашаюсь. При истощении всякой положительной силы и воли, имею еще
>   волю и силу отрицательныя. Я совершенно обезоружен для действия: но
>   еще достаточно вооружен для противодействия пассивного (слово
>   страдательное как-то худо выражет это понятие). Вяземский Стар. зап.
>   кн. // ПСС 10 269.

[**Кадавер**-курсы — это уроки, проводимые на трупах.](http://www.beautyinsider.ru/2014/03/09/cadaver-in-paris-foe-estetique-therapists/)

---

Можно сказать, что в языке сохранилось слово "кадавр", в общем или переносном значении означающее труп, и специальное - медицинское и полицейско-протокольное - "кадавер". Произносится со смягчённым *в*. То есть как пишется, так и слышится.

Answer (score 1):

Кадавр и кадавер - это разные слова общего происхождения. Если обобщать данные из нескольких словарей (викисловарь, например), то значений у слова Кадавр несколько.

1. То же, что и кадавер (уст.).
2. упырь, вурдалак.
3. некое искусственное существо, гомункулус выведенное братьями Стругацкими в повести "Понедельник начинается в субботу" и приобретшее самостоятельное значение, которое, правда, не просто сформулировать.

Кадавер (тоже уст) - медицинский и околомедицинский термин, умирающий больной. В этом значении "кадавер" и "кадавр" можно считать фонетическими вариантами. Других значений не имеет.

Таким образом, кадавер/кадавр в медицинском применении в целом устарело (исключение, возможно, "кадав(е)р-класс" - практикум на трупах, "анатомический театр"), а другие значения не имеют варианта с гласным.

Что касается произношения, то вопрос спорный. Но в целом этот конечный элемент "ер" в заимствованных словах обычно произносится по общим правилам русского языка, то есть со смягчением предыдущего согласного. Так что я за произношение "кадавер". Впрочем, как уже сказал, сейчас это слово в таком виде уже не актуально.